# How can I grep for a count of pipes ('|')?

Tags: grep

I have tried:

```
 grep -c "\|" *.*
```

But it didn't work, since it gives an incorrect count of consecutive pipes.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you really want "*.*"?  That will exclude files that don't have a dot in the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, using Perl, is:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){$c+=tr/|/|/};print "$c\n"' *
```

In non-one-liner format that's:

```
while(<>){
    $c += tr/|/|/
}
print "$c\n"
```

The `while(<>){` line is Perl magic for reading lines from files on the command or from `STDIN`.  You get used to it after a while.  The line itself goes into a variable called `$_`, which is the default parameter for many Perl commands.  For instance `tr`, which works quite a bit like `tr(1)`, defaults to operating on `$_`.  I'm putting my results in a global variable called `$c`.  (In a full program, it's best to declare it a lexical variable with `my $c = 0;` outside the loop.)  The `+=` operator adds the result of the `tr` command (the number of pipe characters in this case) to the current value of `$c`.

Just using `tr(1)` is clearly a simpler option. ;-)

Using `*.*` is a DOSism that you don't likely want to use on a UNIX-like platform.

Using single quotes to avoid having the shell interpret the pipe character reads a bit better.  For instance, I tested my answer with:

```
$ echo '||||
|||||' | perl -e 'while(<>){$c+=tr/|/|/};print "$c\n"'
9
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `tr(1)` to delete all non-pipe characters and then use `wc(1)` to get a total:

```
cat *.* | tr -d -c '|' | wc -c
```

Answer (score 6):

It's counterintuitive, but in most unix regex, escaping the `|` makes it the or-operator.  So your line is actually matching "nothing or nothing" (you can test this out by add some alternatives on either side).  Just use

```
grep -c "|" *.*
```

Secondly, grep counts lines, not character occurrences.  You could use a different tool; or, if you insist on grep, you could put each "|" on its own line. For example, with sed:

```
sed 's/|/|\n/g' *.*
```

Note: if using sed, I advise a *lot* of testing to make sure it does what you think it does.  I needed to just then.

Finally, combine the ingredients:

```
cat *.*  |  sed 's/|/|\n/g'  |  grep -c "|"
```

Unfortunately this might not work for you, as you're probably not using unix (because of the `*.*`).  But hopefully it explains the problem, which I always find strangely reassuring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a number of pipes, then

```
fgrep -o "|" | wc -l
```

If you want to find a number of lines with at least one pipe, then

```
fgrep -c "|"
```

Answer (score -3):

try

```
grep -c "\|" *.*
```

and read some tutorials about bash

Comment: Will give incorrect count if there are multiple pipes on the same line.